# How to determine whether files are downloaded serially or in parallel using Wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

In the http-ethereal-trace provided in the link below there are three HTTP GET request.The 2nd and 3rd request downloads a GIF and JPG format image recpectively.How can we determine wether the two files are downloaded in serial or parallel manner looking at the HTTP and TCP connections made? Kindly explain in detail.

link:- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wa7G9TCjoouUYYyrczfAaN1JQafU-hHI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in parallel, which you can see in any convenient capture tool.
They are in parallel because **the second one opens before processing has finished on the first one.**  Indeed, processing hasn't even started.

We see two TCP opens a few millseconds apart, one on port 4308 and one on port 4309:

```
06:38:41.734948 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 694, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    192.168.1.102.4308 > 165.193.123.218.80: Flags [S], seq 4246632680, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
06:38:41.736408 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 699, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    192.168.1.102.4309 > 134.241.6.82.80: Flags [S], seq 4246666212, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

We identify the streams from their fetches, a little later where segments show the fetches from port 4308 for the GIF and 4309 for the JPEG:

```
06:38:41.756098 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 703, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 611)
    192.168.1.102.4308 > 165.193.123.218.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:572, ack 1, win 64860, length 571: HTTP, length: 571
    GET /catalog/images/pearson-logo-footer.gif HTTP/1.1
    ...
06:38:41.759416 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 705, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 595)
    192.168.1.102.4309 > 134.241.6.82.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:556, ack 1, win 64240, length 555: HTTP, length: 555
    GET /~kurose/cover.jpg HTTP/1.1
    ...
```

The output above was done with tcpdump capture tool, filtering on TCP steams.

```
tcpdump -n -v -K -r http-ethereal-trace-4 ip proto \\tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

Use wireshark and go to `edit --> preferences` and chose

`appearance --> columns`

There I would add a new column, than give it a name like `stream-idx` and use `tcp.stream` as the field value.

Now you have the Stream-Index number for each packet in your summary-line  and you can see if your streams are handled in parallel or not.

Background is, that normally a separate stream is used for each GET request.

But I think your example is not the best to demonstrate this, because the files, especially the gif, are to small.